# No output when traversing SOCKS5 proxy with Fabric/Paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, fabric, paramiko

When trying to traverse a SOCKS5 proxy to a RHEL5 Linux host using Fabric 1.6, the command returns but no output is returned to the stdout.

```
$> fab -H myhost -f ./fabfile.py remote_test --show=debug
Using fabfile '/home/myuser/fabric/fabfile.py'
Commands to run: remote_test
Parallel tasks now using pool size of 1
[myhost] Executing task 'remote_test'
[myhost] run: echo testing
Enter SOCKS5 password for myuser:
[myhost] Login password for 'myuser':
$> echo $?
0
$>
```

The remote_test function is:

```
def remote_test():
    run('echo testing')
```

If I run the command against a non SOCKS5 host it works fine.

I am running the latest builds, although I haven't to date gotten this to work:

Python 2.7.3

Paramiko == 1.10.0

pycrypto == 2.6

fabric == 1.6.0

RHEL5.9

openssh-4.3p2-82.el5

My ~/.ssh/config looks like the following:

```
Host *.domain
    ProxyCommand connect  -S socksproxy.domain:1080 %h %p
```

And using the connect binary built from http://www.meadowy.org/~gotoh/ssh/connect.c

I haven't got access to github from the Company network so I will ask there when I get a chance as well.

Has anyone got any ideas why this could be occuring?

Thanks
Matt

Comment: don't use parallel when only making one connection, and/or using stdin.

Comment: Not using parallel mode at this time, regardless its prompting for passwords which cant be handled in parallel mode anyway due to ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

I use `connect` rather than fabric but the answer is surely the same.  There is an explination in `connect.c` that the `SOCKS5_PASSWORD`, `HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD`, and `CONNECT_PASSWORD` do what you want.  I've a script called `ssh-tbb` that goes as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
export CONNECT_PASSWORD=""
exec ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p" $*
```

Ideally, one should call this script `ssh-tor` and detect if `tor` lives on port 9050 or 9150 of course.